# How to add spaces between values in xml?

Tags: php, xml

I have to create an `xml` out of other `xml`. I already have the answer to that, but then I'm facing another problem. The output of the `xml` is quite messy in the  tag.

The xml is this:

```
<rss>
  <item id="12907">
    <g:productname>Black Bag</g:productname>
      <g:detailed_images>
          <g:detailed_image>Image1.jpg</g:detailed_image>
          <g:detailed_image>Image2.jpg</g:detailed_image>
          <g:detailed_image>Image3.jpg</g:detailed_image>
          <g:detailed_image>Image4.jpg</g:detailed_image>
          <g:detailed_image>Image5.jpg</g:detailed_image>
          <g:detailed_image>Image6.jpg</g:detailed_image>
          <g:detailed_image>Image7.jpg</g:detailed_image>
          <g:detailed_image>Image8.jpg</g:detailed_image>
          <g:detailed_image>Image9.jpg</g:detailed_image>
          <g:detailed_image>Image10.jpg</g:detailed_image>
          <g:detailed_image>Image11.jpg</g:detailed_image>
          <g:detailed_image>Image12.jpg</g:detailed_image>
      </g:detailed_images>    
  </item>
  <item id="12906">
    <g:productname>Yellow Bag</g:productname>
      <g:detailed_images>
          <g:detailed_image>Image1.jpg</g:detailed_image>
          <g:detailed_image>Image2.jpg</g:detailed_image>
          <g:detailed_image>Image3.jpg</g:detailed_image>
          <g:detailed_image>Image4.jpg</g:detailed_image>
          <g:detailed_image>Image5.jpg</g:detailed_image>
          <g:detailed_image>Image6.jpg</g:detailed_image>
          <g:detailed_image>Image7.jpg</g:detailed_image>
          <g:detailed_image>Image8.jpg</g:detailed_image>
          <g:detailed_image>Image9.jpg</g:detailed_image>
          <g:detailed_image>Image10.jpg</g:detailed_image>
          <g:detailed_image>Image11.jpg</g:detailed_image>
          <g:detailed_image>Image12.jpg</g:detailed_image>
      </g:detailed_images>
  </item>
</rss>
```

The `php` code that I'm using to create another `xml` file is this

```
<?php 
    $document = new DOMDocument;
    $document->formatOutput = true;
    $document->preserveWhiteSpace = false;       
    $document->load('xml_feeds.xml');
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($document);

    $fields = [
        'productname' => 'string(g:productname)',
        'detailed_images' => 'string(g:detailed_images)'
    ];

    $xml = new DOMDocument;
    $xml->formatOutput = true;    
    $xml->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
    $rss = $xml->appendChild($xml->createElement('rss'));

    foreach ($xpath->evaluate('//item') as $item) {
        //create tag item
        $createItem = $rss->appendChild($xml->createElement('item'));

        //getting item's attribute value
        $valueID = $item->getAttribute('id');

        //create attribute
        $itemAttribute = $xml->createAttribute('id');
        $itemAttribute->value = $valueID;
        $createItem->appendChild($itemAttribute);

        foreach ($fields as $caption => $expression) {
            $value = $xpath->evaluate($expression, $item);
            $createItem->appendChild($xml->createElement($caption, $value));
        }        
    }

    $xml->save('new_createxml2.xml');
?>
```

The result of the `new_createxml2.xml` is this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<rss>
  <item id="12907">
    <productname>Black Bag</productname>
    <detailed_images>Image1.jpgImage2.jpgImage3.jpgImage4.jpgImage3.jpgImage4.jpgImage5.jpgImage6.jpgImage7.jpgImage8.jpgImage9.jpgImage10.jpgImage11.jpgImage12.jpg</detailed_images>
  </item>
  <item id="12906">
    <productname>Yellow Bag</productname>
    <detailed_images>Image1.jpgImage2.jpgImage3.jpgImage4.jpgImage3.jpgImage4.jpgImage5.jpgImage6.jpgImage7.jpgImage8.jpgImage9.jpgImage10.jpgImage11.jpgImage12.jpg</detailed_images>
  </item>
</rss>
```

I really wonder how can I create the xml tidier than what I've made. I want it to display like this actually:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<rss>
  <item id="12907">
    <productname>Black Bag</productname>
    <detailed_images>Image1.jpg, Image2.jpg, Image3.jpg, Image4.jpg, Image3.jpg, Image4.jpg, Image5.jpg, Image6.jpg, Image7.jpg, Image8.jpg, Image9.jpg, Image10.jpg, Image11.jpg, Image12.jpg</detailed_images>
  </item>
  <item id="12906">
    <productname>Yellow Bag</productname>
    <detailed_images>Image1.jpg, Image2.jpg, Image3.jpg, Image4.jpg, Image3.jpg, Image4.jpg, Image5.jpg, Image6.jpg, Image7.jpg, Image8.jpg, Image9.jpg, Image10.jpg, Image11.jpg, Image12.jpg</detailed_images>
  </item>
</rss>
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: post the code you have tried

Comment: @PrasannaVenkatesh  Read the question completely first.

Comment: what have you done to add comma

Comment: @PrasannaVenkatesh  The op has given a neat piece of code regarding how he has solved the problem of creating the second xml. Adding the comma is what he needs to do and he is anticipating suggestions regarding the same.

Comment: @PrasannaVenkatesh I haven't done anything to add the comma, I did it manually. It's the output that I actually wanted, but I can't do it by using php.

Comment: @rhog23 you can do it. You try yourself that will help you in learning things. If you start to rise questions for all your queries you can't learn.

Comment: The string() function in your xpath expression returns the text content of all child nodes in your node list concatenated together. If you want them joined with a comma then you will need to iterate the elements and collect their text content and join them with a `, `

Comment: @rhog23 Is `$createItem->appendChild($xml->createElement($caption, $value));` responsible for creating your inner elements? If so, you can check the `$caption` value for `detailed_images` if that is the case do some string manipulation with `$value` field to insert commas after the file extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you've tried it is quite simple for some things, but as you've found out that this method fails when you want processing for each individual piece of data.  When you use `'string(g:detailed_images)'` - this is the text content of all of the subnodes in your document, which is why you have all of the values stuck together.  You could then process this string with some form of regular expression - but as you have no control of the content it's difficult to know what you are going to find.

Changing it to a more traditional - get values using a specific XPath call and processing the values allows you more control over the result.

```
foreach ($xpath->evaluate('//item') as $item) {
    //create tag item
    $createItem = $rss->appendChild($xml->createElement('item'));

    //getting item's attribute value
    $valueID = $item->getAttribute('id');

    //create attribute
    $itemAttribute = $xml->createAttribute('id');
    $itemAttribute->value = $valueID;
    $createItem->appendChild($itemAttribute);

    $prodName = $xpath->evaluate("string(g:productname)", $item);
    $createItem->appendChild($xml->createElement('productname', $prodName));
    $images = [];
    foreach ( $xpath->query("descendant::g:detailed_image", $item) as $image )    {
        $images[] = $image->nodeValue;
    }
    $createItem->appendChild($xml->createElement('detailed_images',
            implode(",", $images)));
}
```

Comment: Nigel, thank you so much for the answer! I need to change a bit though, the `query("//g:detailed_image"` to `query("//item[@id=" . $valueID . "/g:detailed_images/g:detailed_image"`. I did that because without specifying the attribute id, the query return all the detailed_images in every <item> into each <item> (One <item> has the value of detailed_image of every item). Aside from that the code works fine, Nigel.

Comment: The important thing is that you can understand it enough to change it.  A shorter version would be `descendant::g:detailed_image`, `descendant` says to just use elements inside the start point.